# how to append text to lines of texbox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events, textbox

I'm using the following code in `_TextChanged`:

```
string[] currentLines = new string[text.Lines.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < currentLines.Length; i++) {
       currentLines[i] = text.Lines[i] + "...";
}

text.Lines = currentLines;
```

that's crashing when event is called. I have no idea how to fix this, the crash occurring when I do this:

```
text.Lines = currentLines;
```

why's that and how to fix? Thanks in advance.

Comment: wrap it in a try catch block and see what line is failing.  Probably text is null.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: winForms. I added in tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution:

For a reason that I don't know(if you know, explain for me, please), this crash occurs only with `TextBox`, I replaced to a `RichTextBox` and it works fine now.

Answer (score 4):

Setting Lines may trigger the `_TextChanged` event again.  What is the error you are getting?  If you see a StackOverflowException, this is the cause.

You could possibly add this to get around the problem, or take the bool flag approach Daniel mentioned in his answer.

```
text.TextChanged -= textBox1_TextChanged;

text.Lines = currentLines;

text.TextChanged += textBox1_TextChanged;
```

Also, perhaps this [question discussing the difference between programmatic changes and user driven changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7271101/wpf-textbox-textchanged-event-on-programmatic-vs-user-change-of-text-contents) is of interest to you.

Comment: This is probably the cause of the exception.

Comment: I don't get some exception,the program lock simply.

Comment: +1 Yep, that seems to be the case. Event handler should be disabled momentarily and reset after `text.Lines = currentLines;`

Comment: That's most likely a `StackOverflowException`.

Comment: @Jack: Precisely, your program enters an ongoing loop. You are modyfying the `TextBox's` text inside the `TextChanged` event handler which fires the event again which makes the event handler execute again which modifies the text...an so on ;)

Comment: I treid run it `
        private void text_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                code..
            }
            catch (Exception E)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(E.Message);
            }
        }` don't returns exception.

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth: There is no `StackOverflowException`. There is no recursive call here, its just one method being executed non stop sequentially with no way to exit.

Comment: @InBetween: Hm, you mean because TextChanged is not a synchronous event directly related to setting the `Lines` property but in reaction to a windows message?

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth: +1 Actually you are right, my bad. Event does fire synchronously and you eventually get a SO exception (I thought it didn't). It just takes a while ;)

Answer (score 1):

As Adam S notes in his answer, you are most likely getting a `StackOverflowException` because of endless recursion. You can try to fix it like this:

```
private void _TextChanged(...)
{
    static bool settingLines = false;
    if(settingLines)
        return;

    string[] currentLines = new string[text.Lines.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < currentLines.Length; i++) {
           currentLines[i] = text.Lines[i] + "...";
    }

    settingLines = true;

    text.Lines = currentLines;

    settingLines = false;
}
```

This solution is not thread safe but that is not a problem in your case as you are interacting with UI controls anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try unsubscribing from the `_TextChanged` event before the problematic line, and re-subscribing after it.