# wpf textBox Text Changed event

Tags: c#, wpf, database, textbox

A table contains ID, Name, Job in database and 3 textboxes on wpf window.
I want, when ID textbox change, fills two other textboxes from database. I only can do it with comboBox_SelectionChanged.

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/textbox-wpf || http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7271101/wpf-textbox-textchanged-event-on-programmatic-versus-user-change-of-text-content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MVVM pattern to accomplish the same. I will try to explain the involved steps in brief.

1. Create a VM(View Model) class and inherit the same from
   INotifyPropertyChanged.
2. Implement the PropertyChanged event.
3. Define a function that will Notify the property changes. This function will
   be called by Set accessor of each property that needs notification
   whenever a property changes.
4. Declare three properties namely ID, Name and Job inside the class.
   Bind each of the properties with their respective textbox controls. 
   Inside the ID property, set the value of other two controls.

Use the link below for better understanding.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

u can use TextChanged event for a text box.compare the id value with the value in database.if it equals,then retrieve the respective name and job for that id through database